# How to reconfigure *many* Thunderbird accounts to reference new mail server

Tags: configuration, command-line-interface, mail-server, thunderbird

I have been using a web host for more than a decade, but their service keeps getting worse and their prices keep getting higher. So, I'm switching to a different web host.

I have, uh, let's go with "too many" email addresses defined in my domain. I use Thunderbird (in Ubuntu) as my mail client, and it works really well for this.

But now I need to go through "too many" email accounts in Thunderbird to update the mail server to my new host. This is especially inconvenient because when you change the mail server for an account, Thunderbird requires you to immediately close and reopen the application to save the change. That turns a slow, tedious process of "click, click, triple-click, paste, repeat" into a ridiculously slow, tedious process of "click, click, triple-click, paste, click, click, wait for the application to close, wait for the application to open, paste in the correct password for the changed account, repeat."

I know that Thunderbird has a CLI, but I've not been able to find any documentation for setting mail servers that way.

Is there any other way to "hack" the files (e.g., with `sed`) to change the mail server (smtp and pop3|imap, accordingly) and then only have Thunderbird query for all my passwords on next open?

I've tried a global search-and-replace of the old server ID to the new one in the `logins.json` file while the application wasn't running. The only result of that I could see was that on next launch I had a `logins.json.corrupt` file in my directory, and a new `logins.json` file with the old server name in it. So apparently *that* isn't the right file (or, at least it's not the right file in isolation).

Comment: I *think* I've found the solution for this, but in my current test bed I only have IMAP accounts. So, I'll need to try it before I post something here. It involves more than a dozen `sed` commands, and running some SQL against two of the sqlite files. Once I try it against my full instance, I'll post the process here for future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

The following is provided with ***absolutely no warranty***. It appears to have worked for me, but I make no promises that it will work for you or that it won't corrupt your entire Thunderbird instance. Follow these instructions at your own risk.

These steps were performed in an instance of Ubuntu 20.04. Adjustments may be required based on your environment. Make sure Thunderbird is not running before you start.

These commands assume that you are migrating from something like "mail.server.oldcompany.com" to "mail.host.newbusiness.net"

Begin by making a backup of your Thunderbird environment, just in case.

```
tar -czfv ~/.thunderbird.tar.gz ~/.thunderbird
```

Instal DB Browser (or your choice of other sqlite database tool)

Inside your ~/.thunderbird directory, you'll find a directory that starts with what, to me, look like 8 random characters, followed by ".default-release", e.g. kg5fvku6.default-release. I'll use this name in the following command, but you should substitute your own folder name.

Use DB Browser to open the ~/.thunderbird/kg5fvku6.default-release/global-messages-db.sqlite database.
Browse Data on the folderLocations table, and note that the folderURI value is potentially problematic column.
On the Execute SQL tab, use:

```
UPDATE folderLocations
SET folderURI = REPLACE(folderURI, 'server.oldcompany.com', 'host.newbusiness.net')
where true
```

(Save)

Use DB Browser to open the ~/.thunderbird/kg5fvku6.default-release/permissions.sqlite database.
Browse Data on the moz_perms table, and note that the origin column is potentially problematic.
On the Execute SQL tab, use:

```
UPDATE moz_perms
SET origin = REPLACE(origin, 'server.oldcompany.com', 'host.newbusiness.net')
where true
```

(Save)

I ran this in two environments. One had "logins.msf" and "logins-backup.msf" files, and the other had "logins.json" and "logins-backup.json" files. If your environment has json files instead of msf files, change these first two commands accordingly.

Run the following 13 commands to do find/replace across these files.

```
sed -i 's/server.oldcompany.com/host.newbusiness.net/g' ~/.thunderbird/kg5fvku6.default-release/logins.msf
sed -i 's/server.oldcompany.com/host.newbusiness.net/g' ~/.thunderbird/kg5fvku6.default-release/logins-backup.msf
sed -i 's/server.oldcompany.com/host.newbusiness.net/g' ~/.thunderbird/kg5fvku6.default-release/ImapMail/vaportrail.asoshared-*.com/INBOX
sed -i 's/server.oldcompany.com/host.newbusiness.net/g' ~/.thunderbird/kg5fvku6.default-release/ImapMail/vaportrail.asoshared-*.com/INBOX.sbd/Trash.msf
sed -i 's/server.oldcompany.com/host.newbusiness.net/g' ~/.thunderbird/kg5fvku6.default-release/folderCache.json
sed -i 's/server.oldcompany.com/host.newbusiness.net/g' ~/.thunderbird/kg5fvku6.default-release/prefs.js
sed -i 's/server.oldcompany.com/host.newbusiness.net/g' ~/.thunderbird/kg5fvku6.default-release/folderTree.json
sed -i 's/server.oldcompany.com/host.newbusiness.net/g' ~/.thunderbird/kg5fvku6.default-release/virtualFolders.dat
sed -i 's/server.oldcompany.com/host.newbusiness.net/g' ~/.thunderbird/kg5fvku6.default-release/Mail/smart\ mailboxes/Sent.msf
sed -i 's/server.oldcompany.com/host.newbusiness.net/g' ~/.thunderbird/kg5fvku6.default-release/Mail/smart\ mailboxes/Drafts.msf
sed -i 's/server.oldcompany.com/host.newbusiness.net/g' ~/.thunderbird/kg5fvku6.default-release/Mail/smart\ mailboxes/Junk.msf
sed -i 's/server.oldcompany.com/host.newbusiness.net/g' ~/.thunderbird/kg5fvku6.default-release/Mail/smart\ mailboxes/Inbox.msf
sed -i 's/server.oldcompany.com/host.newbusiness.net/g' ~/.thunderbird/kg5fvku6.default-release/Mail/smart\ mailboxes/Trash.msf
```

Then, from ~/.thunderbird, run this:

```
grep -rnH server.oldcompany.com ./ > ~/lookForOldCompany.txt
```

Look through that text file. (Expect it to be large.)
Everything *should* be on the order of a "Received: from server.oldcompany.com" or "by server.oldcompany.com", with an additional entry of "Binary file ./kg5fvku6.default-release/global-messages-db.sqlite matches" for things within the headers of individual messages. If you find additional files that have what appear to be indications of mail account connection information, run a sed against those files, too. It doesn't seem to be necessary to rename the actual directories that are holding the mail data, so don't worry about that.

When you've done this, launch Thunrderbird. It might query you for passwords to some account, but it might not. I've seen some inconsistenty there.

If this completely causes a crash-and-burn of your Thunderbird environment, here's how you recover:

1. Make sure Thunderbird isn't running.
2. Delete your ~/.thunderbird directory.
3. Extract your saved tarball back into place. (`tar -xzf .thunderbird.tar.gz`)

Good luck!